# Python (2.7) prints hexadecimal instead special characters

Tags: python, character-encoding

I don't know what happened but I was working with reading files and processing XML with SAX. One '€' character caused an exception so I was trying with decode/encode.

The issue is that before I could do this:

```
>>> line = '€'
>>> line
'€'
```

And now it works like this:

```
>>> line = '€'
>>> line
'\xe2\x82\xac'
```

This is for all special characters, like: á, é, í, and so on.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you were ever able to get the former to work? It shouldn't, at least not with the Python REPL.

Comment: Are you sure you was using python2 (and not 3) for your first test?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.If it's of any help I was using the python console of PyCharm (4.0.4). And the exact python version is 2.7.8.

Comment: Use Python 3 instead of Python 2.7, and you see the `€` correctly. Before you must have been using Python 3.

Comment: If you are using Python 2.7, I would recommend you use the `unicode` type instead of `str`. In Unicode `€` is just another character and is no more special than any other. As a hint, the hex code `\xe2\x82\xac` is the UTF-8 encoding for `€`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unicode type:

```
>>> line = u'€'
>>> print(line)
€
```

When dealing with character sets, it is always important to know which codec your are decoding from, and encoding to.

For reference, I'm using Python 2.7.8.